# Curve from Mesh, how to enable handles?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I'm trying to enable the **handles** of Control Points in a **Curv**e that I got **from Mesh**, selecting the Control Points and pressing <kbd>V</kbd> didn't get any results, I tried all types of Control Points. Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Toggle *Edit Mode* and set Spline Type to *Bezier*.

[image]

*Tool Shelf <kbd>T</kbd> > Tools > Curve Tools > Set Spline Type:*

[image]

Here is an explanation from the [Blender Reference Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/curves/editing/introduction.html#convert-mesh-to-curve):

> Mesh objects that consist of a series of connected vertices can be
>   converted into curve objects. The resulting curve will be a Poly curve
>   type, but can be converted to have smooth segments as described above.

Comment: Many thanks, I had also to increase the Resolution under Curve Properties, looks like by default it's 0 when making a Curve from Mesh.

Comment: Glad to help you. About the resolution, Render U: 0 means that Blender will use the same value set for Preview U (default: 12). If you do not use a lower value for the preview, I suggest you to leave Render U value unchanged (0)

Comment: I was actually talking about resolution under Active SPline to be more specific, Because when I changed the curve to bezier, that activated the handles, but changing them didn't change anything.

Comment: I also had to set Handles to "auto" or "align" or "free".